# flutter firebase firestore - 'id' return randomly - can't get the id of my documents

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a view displaying several documents. I am using a listview.builder.
Each document field name is displayed on a card.
I am using an onTap function.
So with the onTap on a card, I am getting an other view displaying the records of the list stored in a document.
I need to get the id of the document selected. I have tried, but I am getting a random id which is not contained in my collection, neither in my documents.

Bellow, you will find a screenshot of two id I am trying to get.

Please, can you advise? Many thanks.

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /1.4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child:StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                  .collection('lists')
                  .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                
                QuerySnapshot data = snapshot.requireData;

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    Map item = data.docs[index].data();

                      return InkWell(
                        child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset('assets/icons/checklist.png'),//Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
                              title:Text((item['listName'])),
                              subtitle: Text(item['allItems'].length.toString())),
                            ),
                      onTap:(){
                          
                          Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailScreen_CheckList_V3(item),));

                  },
                );
```

```
class _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State extends State<DetailScreen_CheckList_V3> {
  Map listName;

  _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State(
      this.listName
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DocumentReference doc_ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('lists').doc();

    print('my id');
    print (doc_ref);


    var testID = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('lists')
        .doc()
        .id;

    print (testID);

    return Scaffold(
     key :_scaffoldKey ,
      appBar:AppBar (
        title: Text('Your list items'),
        leading:
        InkWell(
          child:
          Icon(Icons.fast_rewind_outlined),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },),

      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an InkWell to do that, you can use the "onTap" property from ListTile, example:

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  Map item = data.docs[index].data();
  return ListTile(
    leading: Image.asset(
        'assets/icons/checklist.png'), //Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
    title: Text((item['listName'])),
    subtitle: Text(item['allItems'].length.toString()),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailScreen_CheckList_V3(item)));
    },
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you. And what about my initial question on getting the ID, do you know why I am not getting it? thank you